# Db2 XML replacing

Tags: xml, db2, db2-400

My code:

```
Set ls_xml='<root><name>Johnbrick</name></root>


Replace the name to 'Michale dukes' in db2 XML.
Can anyone give solution for this.
```

Expexted result in XML:

```
 Set ls_xml='<root><name>micheal Dukes</name></root>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
XMLQUERY( 'transform
  copy $v2 := $v1
  modify
    do replace value of $v2/root/name with
      "Michale dukes"
  return $v2'
  passing doc as "v1")
FROM (
  select xmlparse(document '<root><name>Johnbrick</name></root>') doc
  from sysibm.sysdummy1
) x;
```

Checked with Db2 v11.5.

Db2 for i (AS/400, iSeries), which is also tagged to this question, currently does not offer the capabilities to transform XML documents with XPath, only providing lookup/search options.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

One more question in tat..

                   DECLARE Ls_Name='Michale dukes';
                   Set ls_xml='<root><name>Johnbrick</name></root>

How to handle this with the help of Local Variable.

@Maksim Zinal